Block Group Policy from applying for specific computers where users allowed
I have seen this question asked before but not in this same way.
We have a group policy configured for users that is applied at an OU.  That policy has a Security Filter set to only allow the policy for users of a specific security group.  So far that is working exactly as expected.
Now, in a completely different OU, where this policy is not applied, it is still being applied, I'm assuming because the user logging into this PC is a member of that other OU they are still getting the policy.
I thought I could create another group containing the PCs that I don't want this policy applied to and then put this in the delegation tab and deny the policy for those computers.  But when I run the GPRESULT command it shows that the policy was denied for the Computer settings but it shows as applied for the User settings.
Is there a way to accomplish what I want here?
I want to apply a policy to specific users on every machine they connect to but a specific handful.

User policies are by default applied from the user OU structure.
To prevent the OU structure policies from conflicting when logging on at another location, the host may be configured for "Loopback policy processing":
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Group Policy
"Configure user Group Policy loopback processing mode"
When the host is configured, it may also specify that the user OU policies are merged or replaced.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/askds/circle-back-to-loopback/400212

Yes it's possible, because the computers must be able to Read the GPO from the domain controllers before applying it (even for the User settings).
So, use the group containing the PCs you want to exclude, add it to the delegation tab and deny the "Read" right (not the "Apply Group Policy", useless in your context). Computers will no longer be able to read the GPO and will therefore not apply it.
You can read this blog post if you want more details about this feature (it was introduced as a security fix): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/deploying-group-policy-security-update-ms16-072-kb3163622
Quote from this blog post:

When a user group policy is retrieved using the computer's security context, the computer account will now need "read" access to retrieve the group policy objects (GPOs) needed to apply to the user.


User policies are applied to users, regardless of which computer they are using.
Computer policies are applied to computers, regardless of which user is using them.
This can be overriden by loopback processing.
